# How To Target A Specific PHP Function Using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am creating a simple comment program. i want to use ajax to refresh the comments and total number of comments. Keeping both functions in a single file is not working for me.

here is my code:

HTML:

```
<h3></h3>
<ul>
        
</ul>
```

PHP: include.php

```
//for comments
function main(){
    try {
        $query = connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE article_id = 1627359589");
        $query->execute();
        echo json_encode($query->fetchAll());

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("database connection failed");
    }
}

// for total comment
function totalComment(){
        $sql ="SELECT * FROM comments WHERE article_id = 1627359589";
        $stmt = connect()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $num = $stmt->rowCount();
        echo json_encode($num);
}

main();
totalComment();
```

AJAX:

```
// for comment
setInterval(displayComments, 2000);

function displayComments(){
       $.ajax({
            url: "include.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data){
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $("ul").append("<li>"+data[i] + "</li>")
                }
            }
        })
}

// for total comments
setInterval(total, 2000);
function total(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "include.php",
                success: function(data){
                    $("h3").html(data);
                }
              
            })
    }
```

Comment: Neither ajax request is sending any data but if you wish to target the same script and execute different functions you will need to send some named data and use that in php to fork the logic and execute the necessary function

Comment: Seeing that you want to call both functions with the same frequency, it might be a bit more performant to make just one request where you return both results in one single json. Something like: `echo json_encode(['comments' => main(), 'totalCount' => totalComment()]);`. Just make sure that you then just `return` the results from the functions instead of json encode and echo them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the PHP to process a named POST item and use `switch` to determine which function to use:

```
<?php
    if( $SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['cmd'] )){
    

        function main(){
            try {
                $query = connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE article_id = 1627359589");
                $query->execute();
                echo json_encode($query->fetchAll());

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                die("database connection failed");
            }
        }

        function totalComment(){
                $sql ="SELECT * FROM comments WHERE article_id = 1627359589";
                $stmt = connect()->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute();
                $num = $stmt->rowCount();
                echo json_encode($num);
        }
        
        
        
        switch( $_POST['cmd'] ){
            case 'comments':
                main();
            break;
            case 'total':
                totalComment();
            break;
            case 'banana':
                banana();
            break;
        }
    }
    
?>
```

In your javascript set the same parameter in each request but with a different value: `data:{cmd:'banana'},` etc

```
function displayComments(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "include.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:{cmd:'comments'},
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data){
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $("ul").append("<li>"+data[i] + "</li>")
            }
        }
    })
}
function total(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "include.php",
        data:{cmd:'total'},
        success: function(data){
            $("h3").html(data);
        }
    })
}


setInterval(displayComments, 2000);
setInterval(total, 2000);
```

Comment: The challenge I'm facing now is that the total comment is empty. It is not actually fetching the total comments I have in my database.

Comment: Got it now. I forgot to add type: 'POST' in the ajax